# SenchaTouch2.0 + socket.io : how to use socket.io.js in SenchTouch2.0

Tags: socket.io, sencha-touch-2

in fact, I had try it,and failed. now the code is:

```
function include(path){ 
var a=document.createElement("script");
a.type = "text/javascript"; 
a.src=path; 
var head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.appendChild(a);
} 
include("app/controller/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js");

Ext.define('WGTalk.controller.guest', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config:{
    refs:{
        viewMsg:'#viewMsg',
        txtMsg:'#txtMsg'
    },
    control:{
        '#btSend':{
            tap:'doSend'
        }
    }
},

launch:function(){
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

        socket.on('connect',function(){
            console.log("connected server");
        });

        socket.on('disconnect',function(){
            console.log("server closed");
        });

        socket.on('message',function(data) { 
            console.log('Received a message from the server: ',data); 
        });
},

doSend:function(){
    var msg = this.getTxtMsg().getValue();
    var msgStore = this.getViewMsg().getStore();
    msgStore.add({name:msg,age:'180'});
    this.getTxtMsg().setValue("");
}
});
```

and the error is: ***ReferenceError: Can't find variable: io  @"var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
" ***

how can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

In your app.json, to load external javascript resources like socket.io, modify as follows:

```
/**
 * List of all JavaScript assets in the right execution order.
 * Each item is an object with the following format:
 * ...
 */
"js": [
    {
        "path": "socket.io.js",
        "x-bootstrap": true
    },
    {
        "path": "json.js",
        "x-bootstrap": true
    },
    ... 
 ]
```

If your mobile app is a client, the above .js are client side socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

Declare io socket inside index.html
like this

```
<script src="http://yourip:port/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```